# Cope extra value from a column of a row to same column of another row in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named Address that contains thousands of rows which comes from two sources eg: X and Y. I want to copy the extra value of Postcode which is the 6-character postcode from Source Y to Source X. I am able to do it by doing insert with conditions, however it's not the best way since it has thousands of rows and the StreetName of the two sources are different eventho it is the same street. Below is how the table looks like.

| Source | City | StreetName | StreetNo | Postcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Pilar | Luis Pasteur | 11 | B123,123 |
| X | Pilar | Luis Pasteur | 12 | B456,456 |
| X | Pilar | Luis Pasteur | 13 | B789,789 |
| Y | Pilar | Calle Luis Pasteur | 11 | B123AB, B123,123 |
| Y | Pilar | Calle Luis Pasteur | 12 | B456CD, B456,456 |
| Y | Pilar | Calle Luis Pasteur | 13 | B789EF, B789,789 |

Is there a way to join a table by itself to achieve what i want? My idea is to join it by the StreetNo.

Comment: `the StreetName of the two sources are different eventho it is the same street` ... you need to give us the logic for how to figure out that it is the same street.  Otherwise, your data has a much bigger problem than the postal codes not matching.

Comment: the street is identified by the matching values of streetno and the subset of postcode. If the values for these column match, means it's the same street. Previously i tried to join it by giving using 'where' condition to state streetname for each source but of course it's not the way to do it :(

Comment: I undeleted my answer below, using the join logic you described in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your data correctly, an update self-join should work here:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.City = t1.City AND
       t2.StreetNo = t1.StreetNo AND
       INSTR(t2.Postcode, t1.Postcode) > 0
SET t1.Postcode = t2.Postcode
WHERE t1.Source = 'X' AND t2.Source = 'Y';
```